# In Dart, in a sequential list of integers, how do I find a number between the items?

Tags: dart

In  a list of sequential integers, is there a simple way to locate where another integer would be placed (between two of the list members)?

```
main() {
var myList = new List();
 myList.addAll([0, 4, 10, 20, 33, 45, 55, 64]);

int setStart;
int currentPosition;

currentPosition = 12; 

// if currentPosition is greater than or equal to myList[fooPosition]
// but less than myList[barPosition]
// setStart = myList[foo]
 }
```

So since the currentPosition is 12, the correct answer for setStart would be 10.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out `package:collection`'s [`binarySearch`](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/collection/latest/collection/binarySearch.html).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out myself. Pretty simple really. I just needed to add another variable (x) to indicate the list position of the upper number:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {

  var x = i + 1;

  if (currentPosition >= myList[i] && currentPosition < myList [x]) {
  setStart = myList[i];
    };
};
```